# Maximum number of edges on a $3-$colorable graph?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring

There is some way to upper bound the number of edges on a $3-$colorable graph $G$, supposing that $G$ has $n$ vertices? I've did some research but haven't found anything that could help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Being 3-colorable is the same as being tripartite. What tripartite graph on $n$ vertices has the most edges?